# jQuery issue with looping ajax on popup box

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have strange issue and I hope you can help me find out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a div called "**popup**" and button "**send_mail**".

When the "**send_mail**" button is pressed, the "**popup**" shows up with the ajax mail form and "**close**" button.

When I fill the mail form and send it, the message is sent to my email address.

Of course at this part everything works flawlessly. So far so good...

The problem is when I open the "**popup**" form, close it using "**close**" button, then reopen the form again and send mail. What's happen is that I get the same mail twice on my mailbox.

Obviously, when I open and close the popup form 10 times and at 10'th time I send the email, I receive 10 mails on my mailbox...

The only way I can fix this and send only one mail is to refresh whole page.

What may that be?

Here is the js code (I'm sorry for chaotic form) :

The very first line is to determine which button is pressed, as there's more than one button in main html page (depends on amount of users, each user has one "send_mail_X" button).

```
$("#list_container").on('click', "[id^='send_mail']", function () {
    var val = $(this).attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/list_class.php",
        data: val,
        success: function(data){

            $("#Popup").on('click', "#close", function () {
                disablePopup();
            });


            $("#Popup").on('submit', "#admin_mail", function () {

                var sendbutton = $(this).find('#sendmail');
                var action = "include/admin_contact.php";
                sendbutton.attr('disabled','disabled');

                $.post(action, {
                    email: $("#Popup").find('#email').val(),
                    title: $("#Popup").find('#title').val(),
                    message: $("#Popup").find('#message').val()
                },
                    function(data){
                        document.getElementById('admin-form_output').innerHTML = data;  
                        centerPopup();
                    }
                );


                return false;



            });


            var array = data.split('#');
            var mymail = array[0];
            var myaddress = array[1];
            var isdisabled = "";
            if(mymail == ""){
                mymail = "Nie można wyslać maila.<br>Brak ardesu email.";
                isdisabled = "disabled='disabled'";
            }
            if(myaddress == ""){
                myaddress = "Uzytkownik nie podał swojego adresu.<br>Zaznacz jego zamowienie na czerwono.";
            }


            $("#bgPopup").data("state",0); 
            loadPopup(); 

            $("#Popup").on('click', "#popupClose", function () {  
                disablePopup();  
                return false;
            }); 



            $("#Popup").html("<a href='#' id='popupClose'><img src='images/close.png'></img></a> <div class='large-notice'><div id='admin-form_output'></div><br /><h4>ADRES WYSYLKOWY:</h4>" + myaddress + "<br /><br /><br /><h4>KONTAKT MAIL:</h4><div id='admin-form'><div class='field' style='display: block;'><form name='admin_mail' id='admin_mail' method='post' action='include/admin_contact.php' ><input type='hidden' name='email' id='email' value='" + mymail + "'/> <input type='text' name='title' id='title' onFocus='if(this.value == \"Tytul wiadomosci\") { this.value = \"\"; }' onBlur='if(this.value == \"\") { this.value = \"Tytul wiadomosci\"; }' value='Tytul wiadomosci' /> <textarea name='message' cols='190' rows='6' id='message' onFocus='if(this.value == \"Wiadomosc\") { this.value = \"\"; }' onBlur='if(this.value == \"\") { this.value = \"Wiadomosc\"; }' value='Wiadomosc'>Wiadomosc</textarea><div class='button'> <br /><input type='submit' class='btn-image' id='sendmail' " + isdisabled + " value='Wyslij' /></div><div class='button'> <br /><input type='button' class='btn-image' id='close' value='Zamknij' /></div></form></div></div><br /><br /><br />" + mymail + "</div>");

            centerPopup();

        }   

    });                                                                 


    return false;
});


function loadPopup(){  
    //loads popup only if it is disabled  

    if($("#bgPopup").data("state")==0){  
        $("#bgPopup").css({  
            "opacity": "0.7"  
        });  
        $("#bgPopup").fadeIn("medium");  
        $("#Popup").fadeIn("medium");
        $("#bgPopup").data("state",1);  
    }  
}  

function disablePopup(){
    $("#Popup").empty();
    if ($("#bgPopup").data("state")==1){  
        $("#bgPopup").fadeOut("medium");  
        $("#Popup").fadeOut("medium");  
        $("#bgPopup").data("state",0);  
    }  
}  

function centerPopup(){ 


    var winw = $(window).width();  
    var winh = $(window).height();  
    var popw = $('#Popup').width();  
    var poph = $('#Popup').height();  
    $("#Popup").css({  
        "position" : "fixed",  
        "top" : winh/2-poph/2,  
        "left" : winw/2-popw/2  
    });  
    //IE6  
    $("#bgPopup").css({  
        "height": winh    
    });  
}
```

Comment: Without the code you use to open the dialog I can't really tell you what's wrong...but I guess that multiple forms are being created. One every time you open the dialog. And when you send the form something weird happens and all of the forms are being submitted. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Edited my question. Didn't post the code before as it's really chaotic :)

Answer (score 0):

put this function in the onclick event of your close button

```
function empty_div(){
    $("#yourmaindiv").html('');
}
```

What it will do is empty your div containing form and its elements.

another possible solution can be to use a random number in the name of your form. So each time a new form is loaded it will have a unique id and name property and you would submit only that form and not all the forms. I think each time your form is loaded they have the same name and that is causing the problem

```
<-form name='myForm2322343233' id='myform2322343233' method='post'    action='somwhere.php'->
```

so each time it has a unique identifier

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Obviously I've already set the `$("#Popup").empty();` code each time when the div with the form is disabled. This didn't change anything. As for the another solution - I would rather know why all the other forms exists, why they are not empty and how to stop the script that being looping them if the forms are not even desired be in the documment. Thanks.